# Initialize OpenCL runtime... OpenCV MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I am detecting faces with Opencv with c++. Until now all my programs executed successfully. but this is giving me error : 
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...
Apples-MacBook:detect_object rushi$ g++ objectDetection.cpp -o out `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
Apples-MacBook:detect_object rushi$ ./out
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
Mat image;
image = imread( "./actress.jpeg", 1 );

if( !image.data )
{
    printf( " No image data \n " );
    return -1;
}

String face_cascade_file = "./haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
CascadeClassifier FaceCascadeClassifier;

// Load the cascade

if (!FaceCascadeClassifier.load(face_cascade_file))
{
    printf("--(!)Error loading cascde classifier...\n");
    return (-1);
}

vector<Rect> faces;
FaceCascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(image, faces, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, Size(30, 30), Size(200,200));

cout<<"faces" <<faces.size();

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kindly have a look on my thread too..

Comment: No one is looking at my question.

Comment: https://answers.opencv.org/question/183442/initialize-opencl-runtime-error/

Looks like you've asked the same question and get answered. Good for you. [ INFO:0] is not an error or even a warning. In your case, it just indicated that the OpenCL is initialized at run-time and getting ready to support cross-platform execution. It has nothing to do with your program fail. Next time please post your full log so that we can identify the problem in specific.